# Laravel 5 Session Lifetime

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

According to Laravel `config/session.php`

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => true,
'expired-session-redirect' => url(env('APP_URL'))
```

I have set the lifetime of my session to `120` minutes, but I have a feeling that my user is log-out way before 120 minutes.

Is that a typo ? Do they mean 120 seconds which is 2 mins ?

Can anyone please shed some lights on this ?

Comment: Check your  `session.gc_maxlifetime` + `session.cookie_lifetime` on your php.ini and make sure you don't clear your browser cookies and the lifetime is set by minutes btw :)

Comment: Will that overwrite my Laravel one?

Comment: It will not overwrite the Laravel one :)

Comment: session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

Comment: session.cookie_lifetime = 0

Comment: These 3 information doesn't to make sense to me. My user seems to log out of the application around 2 minutes, and I don't see 120 seconds anywhere. Do you know what I am trying to understand here ?

Comment: Yes I get it, bwt 1440 secs are 24 minutes, if your user is log out on 2 mins is not a Php.ini problem, seems something is destroying your session on the App.

Comment: That's why I said it doesn't make sense. I am trying to find out what the **exact** time of my user session expiring time.  Where does it get set ? How does it got overwrite ?

Comment: Laravel sessions can expire for a lot of reasons and it is complicated to debug it, I would recommend you to login and navigate / do all the actions you can on your App and then check when you logout what actions you did.

Comment: This is a bit confusing because the Laravel session.lifetime is specified in minutes, but the PHP session.gc_maxlifetime is in seconds. 

And if the gc_maxlifetime is shorter than the Laravel session the CSRF lifetime will only last as long as gc_maxlifetime.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

Answer (score 29):

Check your php.ini for:

**session.gc_maxlifetime** - Default 1440 secs - 24 mins.

**session.gc_maxlifetime** specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage' and potentially cleaned up. Garbage collection may occur during session start (depending on session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor).

**session.cookie_lifetime** - Default 0.

**session.cookie_lifetime** specifies the lifetime of the cookie in seconds which is sent to the browser. The value 0 means "until the browser is closed." Defaults to 0. See also session_get_cookie_params() and session_set_cookie_params().

In case it is less time than the Laravel configuration, the cookie will be removed because the local php.ini have **preference** over Laravel configuration.

You can just increase it or comment/delete.

In case is not solved something on your App is destroying the session.

**UPDATE**

After release [v5.5.22](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/releases/tag/v5.5.22) session lifetime is loaded from `.env` and is not hardcoded anymore at `config/session.php`, changes [there](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/084f10004582299ef3897f6ec14315209d5c1df1#diff-cbfd64a28982a1818f2b5f16e7f9d634).

Now you can modify the session lifetime using:

```
SESSION_LIFETIME=90 //minutes
```

In your `.env` file.

Comment: Is this true even if I use redis as SESSION_DRIVER, or just with file?

Comment: This just saved my sanity checking why CSRF tokens were being invalidated so quickly and why session identifiers were filling up the database backend.

Answer (score 23):

Change `.env` file in your app root

```
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

And value is in minutes.

Comment: This is in terms of minutes ?

Comment: Yes it is in minutes

Answer (score 2):

I found lifetime settings on this place in one project...

*bootstrap/cache/config.php*

so I need to run first

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

Please modify true to false for Expire on close as:

```
'expire_on_close' => false,
```