# laravel 5.3 set session lifetime

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to use laravel to remember the login status. If I check the box remember the login status for 7 days, not check only remember 2 hours.

My thoughts are use the `'config/session.php'` set the lifetime variable for 120min, and then use laravel function like `session('login_status',7days)`, but `session()` doesn't have the parameter to set the lifetime.

Who can give me some ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Session Lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983976/laravel-5-session-lifetime)

Comment: In `config/session.php` set 

`'lifetime' => 10080,`

10080 means 7 days

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a cookie on the clients' browser if you want the client to be logged in longer than the session duration. Laravel itself has an implementation for this using a `remember_token`.

More info about this can be found in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#remembering-users).