# Set the session timeout for specific session - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.1

I want store a certain sesssion, and set it's lifetime to 3 mins only.

```
Session::put('session', $response['session']);
```

I know I can set that in here, app/config/session.php

```
'lifetime' => 3, // = 3 minutes
```

But the goal here to not mess with the main configurarion of the session of the entire app. I want to set the sesssion timeout for that one.

Something like this maybe

```
Session::put('session', $response['session'], 3);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983976/laravel-5-session-lifetime

Comment: You're trying to treat the session like cookies here. Use cookies, instead.

Comment: @Gabriel as I stated, I don't want to set the whole application. I only set for 1 specific session.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy : please answer your suggestion if you don't mind.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy : As suggested, I've tried cookie. I got a weird result and ask a separate question here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/49801840/4480164

Comment: you can use cookie: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#cookies

Comment: I looked at the doc already, I also was here : https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieJar.html

Comment: I think I should stick with Session, and wait until someone give a better hint or possible answer on this.