# Store/Check/Get/List Cookie in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, session-cookies

I just store a cookie into the queue

```
Cookie::queue('session', $response['session'], 3);
```

When I try to list all the cookies in the queue, I got an empty array

```
dd(Cookie::getQueuedCookies()); // I got empty array --->  []


if(Cookie::has('session')) {
    $session = Cookie::get('session');
}
```

What did I miss ?

> This question is about Cookie and **Cookie != Session**

Comment: Please edit your old post but do not use new thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the session timeout for specific session - Laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801237/set-the-session-timeout-for-specific-session-laravel-5-1)

Comment: @Gabriel Session and Cookie is 2 completely diff entity. Why do you think they are the same ?

Comment: what makes you think i can't differentiate session and cookie are the same? I only mean stick with your question and edit accordingly. hope you know the meaning of that.

Comment: They both are complete diff topics and issues. 1 issue on session, 1 issue on cookie, why would I want to merge them ? 

I think they deserve to be in 2 diff post.


If you don't want to answer, please leave my question alone. I would appreciate that. thanks.