# How long can you stay on one page to send POST?

Tags: php, laravel, session, post

I have an unusual problem, namely I am doing an Internet Test, which will take about 60-90 minutes.
Is there a chance that after the 60 minutes the POST test will not be sent because of too long arrival on the site? If so, what does it depend on?

Technlogy: Laravel 5.5
Language: PHP 7.1

Comment: What application is running an Internet Test? What does the Internet Test do? What is sending the POST? What is receiving the POST? So many questions...

Comment: you should research php/server timeouts

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983976/laravel-5-session-lifetime

Answer (score 0):

I assume with an Internet Test you mean something like a survey?

When this means that a user is on a website on your server and he has to answer several questions (on the same page) and after he is finished (~60-90) minutes, he clicks on "submit" button. After that the form will be send to the server with a POST request.

If those assumptions are right, I'd say that there is no POST timeout problem because the connection will just get build up when "submit" is clicked.
Also session variables and other stuff should not be a problem when there are no manually implemented timelimits.

Comment: Thank you! You understood the question perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember that laravel has build in csrf verification. After a session ends or the csrf token changes the post will fail. Maybe add the post route within the $except array in the VerifyCsrfToken.php file.

```
protected $except = [
    '/somthing/something'
]
```