# All the sessions in Laravel are getting logged/wiped out frequently and randomly even when sessions are not idle

Tags: laravel, session

We are using **Laravel 5.5** and we tried both the session drivers (**File and Redis**)

Previously, we were using **File** session driver it was working fine suddenly we faced the issue (All session got destroyed)  and we could not able to find out why, so we changed the session driver as Redis, even then we are facing the same issue

Laravel Session logs out for all the users at the same time **frequently and randomly** even when the session is not idle

Comment: Do you have a `php artisan cache:clear` call somewhere, like in a deployment script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Session Lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983976/laravel-5-session-lifetime)

Comment: the Redis servers port were open and a hacker has put a cron inside the Redis server where it deletes the session :(