# Does Laravel log users off automatically after an interval?

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel and am using Laravel 6. I am working on an app that uses the default authentication for Laravel. I registered myself three times with three different email addresses for testing purposes. I'm finding that after a few hours, I'm logged off and have to log back in again even though I did not click on the logoff option.

Am I correct in assuming there is some kind of default timeout for IDs in Laravel? If so, how to change the interval or disable it altogether?

If that isn't the issue, what could account for me being logged out?

Comment: Look for `lifetime` in `config/session.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Laravel authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) uses `session` driver for `web` guard as default. You can check your default web guard's driver on `config/auth.php`.

```php
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    //...
],
```

The [Laravel session](https://laravel.com/docs/master/session)'s lifetime is 120 minutes by default, You can also check this default value on `config/session.php` as `lifetime` property.

```php
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
```

So you'll be logged off automatically (i.e your session expires) after 2 hours by default.

If you want to stay login for a long time, you have 2 options:

1. Select the "remember me" option when logging into your application (Recommended).
2. Set a large value (e.g 10 years or so) for session's lifetime on local `.env` file. It's not recommended on production environment, because not only authenticated users but also all visitors (including guest, bots etc.) would have a longtime session.

   ```
   SESSION_LIFETIME=5256000 // 10 years
   ```

Comment: I would say it is better to directly manipulate `SESSION_LIFETIME` in the `.env` file.

Comment: @user2094178 it's obvious if you check `config/session.php` that it's using `env('SESSION_LIFETIME')`

Comment: @Hafez - How would I indicate that I don't want my session to time out at all? I'd rather not be bothered with timeouts while I'm developing, although I would obviously turn them back on again when I go to production.

Comment: @Hafez - I tried setting SESSION_LIFETIME to 0 but then it wouldn't let me login at all; it gave me HTTP status of 419.

Comment: @henry There's no "forever" value, but you can set it to 10 years or so SESSION_LIFETIME=5256000

Comment: @Hafez - Okay, thanks for that information. I'll choose a suitable large value to solve the problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you check [CookieSessionHandler::write](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Session/CookieSessionHandler.php#L80-L91) and [CookieSessionHandler::read](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Session/CookieSessionHandler.php#L80-L91):

//write

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function write($sessionId, $data)
{
    $this->cookie->queue($sessionId, json_encode([
        'data' => $data,
        'expires' => $this->availableAt($this->minutes * 60),
    ]), $this->minutes);

    return true;
}
```

//read

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function read($sessionId)
{
    $value = $this->request->cookies->get($sessionId) ?: '';

    if (! is_null($decoded = json_decode($value, true)) && is_array($decoded)) {
        if (isset($decoded['expires']) && $this->currentTime() <= $decoded['expires']) {
            return $decoded['data'];
        }
    }

    return '';
}
```

you can see that there must be some value of time to compare with current time value. Otherwise an empty string is returned and session is being invalidated. Best way you can do is to set config value to something really large (e.g. `35791394` [~68 years in minutes]) This is fail safe for 32-bit systems because it is `2147483640` which is less than signed 32-bit MAX_INT value `2147483647`, just in case. Even if sometimes in future Laravel rewrite session lifetime to use seconds instead of minutes this will last for more than a year.

[Another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983976/laravel-5-session-lifetime).

Comment: Thank you, Tpojka. I've set my SESSION_LIFETIME to 525600, the number of minutes in a year, which should be more than adequate for my purposes. (I just have to remember to set it to a reasonable number once I get it out of test.)