# Laravel Socialite - Logout user on session time out

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I have implemented Laravel (v6) Socialite in my current app. Users are able to login and logout without problems.

I need to set a timeout session because it looks user session keeps live forever, do you know where do I set it?

My main issue is when user suspends their machine and they reactive it.All the session variables that I passed when user logged in are lost and this brings issues to app flows.

Regards!

Comment: did you try to set in config/session.php the lifetime attribute to a diffrent value?

Comment: @Aless55 I will try your approach, thanks!

Comment: @BelisarioPeró Any luck with this? We are seeing similar things.

Comment: I followed this answer: [Laravel 5 Session Lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983976/laravel-5-session-lifetime)

Comment: @Aless55 I followed this approach and it works, but I need to auto logout the user when the session expires. I found many post about it but not working for me.

Comment: Ddd you solve it @JohnC ? I need to auto logout user when session expires, that part is missing for me.

Comment: @JohnC do you have a solution for auto log out user to login page when session expires?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the cookie timeout for what ever socialite provider you are using is the same as your site's session timeout(aka session cookie's timeout) or vise versa. That is, if you want them to be forced to login to recreate the session variables needed.

The other thing to look at is, what are you using to store your session data and how long does it stick around before being deleted. If your storing on disk, and it has a short life time then it will be removed from disk. When the user comes back online it will no longer be there for your app to load into session data.

Our issue was that our sessions were set at the default 2 hours limit. A user would login, get the oauth/socialite long lived session(24 hrs) set along with our session(2 hour). They would then close browser for the day and come back in the morning. They were technically still logged in, according to socialite provider we were using, from the long lived login cookie. But, our session had expired, so the local session data had already been wiped from disk. And since we were setting session variables only upon user login from socialite, the user no longer had the required variables set.

#### Update 6/10/21

Also, make sure that you do not set the remember me flag when you are calling `auth()->login($user)`, when the socialite is calling your callback function after the user logs in. If you do, this will cause your user to stay "logged in" into your app forever, even if your session cookie expired and gets regenerated. Leaving this to false, will have your users stay logged in for as long as the session is active. Aka, the length of time you set your session cookie time to. Next time they hit your site and the session cookie has expired, socialite will redirect them to your oAuth provider to login. Depending on how long you tell your oAuth to keep your login sessions active, this will just be a redirect to oAuth provider and then redirect back to your site's callback url/function. Users won't need to reenter credentials with provider, but the oAuth provider will verify user still has access to login. This will also allow your site to keep your session fresh with up-to-date date/settings.

Comment: great udate! You won't believe it, we can't still solve this.